# Erro no ionic-lab

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Estou fazendo um app, porem quando rodo ionic serve -l ou tendo acessar o ionic-lab pelo navegador ele exive um mensagem de erro e para o servidor, já procurei bastante pela internet e não achei reposta, anexo print do erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problema resolvido após reinstalar o cordova e o ionic(ultimas versoes)